# Custom templates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server(2008 r2) template, within which I have an insert statement. This insert statement uploads a value (nvarchar) which is HTML e.g. `<p>Exeplary text</p>.`

The problem is that the Management Studio treats it as a parameter instead of just a string. How to deal with this?

Comment: if the question I linked to doesn't help, please update your question with an example which shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with the following code:

```
<PayDate,int,> >= <RelDate,int,> % 100
```

After some head scratching, I've added another parameter for the >, as follows:

```
<PayDate,int,> <gt,,>= <RelDate,int,> % 100
```

Then I can specify a value of > for parameter gt when I use the template. A quick test and it seems to work.

You've probably found a solution by now but perhaps this can help someone else.